# Can't load properties from .ini into custom logger

Tags: python, oop, debugging, inheritance, logging

I have a class called `CustomLogger` that is a subclass of `BaseLogger`, which is a subclass of `logging.Logger`. `BaseLogger` loads properties from a `logger.ini` file. So, `CustomLogger` is just a facade for `BaseLogger`.

Here is my code:

**logger.ini**

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,fileHandler

[formatters]
keys=fileFormatter, consoleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=consoleHandler, fileHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=INFO
formatter=consoleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=INFO
formatter=fileFormatter
args=('app.log',)

[formatter_fileFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

[formatter_consoleFormatter]
format=%(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

**base_logger.py**

```py
from os import path
import logging
import logging.config

class BaseLogger(logging.Logger):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)
        config_file_path = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'logger.ini')
        logging.config.fileConfig(config_file_path)
        print("Loaded config level:", self.getEffectiveLevel())
```

**custom_logger.py**

```py
from .base_logger import BaseLogger

class CustomLogger(BaseLogger):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)
```

**main.py**

```py
from custom_logger import CustomLogger

logger = CustomLogger('root')
logger.info("hello") #doesn't work
```

It looks ok, but when i use `CustomLogger` in my code, it doesn't seem to load properties from the .ini file. `getEffectiveLevel()` is returning 0, which indicates that logger level is not being set when instantiated.

I tried using `logging.setLoggerClass`, but also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To use your config file you could do this:

```
import logging.config

logging.config.fileConfig('logger.ini')
root_logger = logging.getLogger('root')
root_logger.info('test')
```

**Update:**

```
# file: custom_logger.py
import logging.config
from custom_logger_second_file import log_message

logging.config.fileConfig('logger.ini')
root_logger = logging.getLogger('root')
root_logger.info('test')
log_message('message from second file')
```

```
# file: custom_logger_second_file.py
import logging.config


def log_message(message):
    root_logger = logging.getLogger('root')
    root_logger.info(message)
```

Comment: I'd like logger to be configured with `fileConfig` just once since it will be available throught all code.

Comment: you can just assign the loger to the same variable in any file `root_logger = logging.getLogger('root')' you'll only have to define the config file once. Check the updated example